# Associate Accounts with other SO family sites?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, linked-accounts

Are you planning in future this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>All associated accounts will appear on the public cv.</s>

<s>Only Stack Overflow accounts will appear on the private cv.</s>

<s>This is by design at the moment.</s>

The above was out of date. **You can selectively hide account associations now.**

Comment: Bummer! It seems like the dummy SO account link would be a big turnoff for someone browsing CVs (of heavy SF users).

Comment: @kara the above was out of date, I updated it.

Comment: Well that's just fantastic.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I do have an account on all 4 trilogy sites, but I am not very active on SF and SU. I would like to be able to select which accounts are shown on the public and which are shown on the private CV.

(Not that I am ashamed of anything I do on these sites, but it does not add to my CV to show that I have 101 rep on SF.)