# Associate other accounts to Careers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

It'd be nice if Careers also allowed association with Server Fault and Super User. Also the inverse would be nice if our CVs were displayed or linked from those sites?

Comment: Do you use Google as your Open ID provider?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24997/associate-account-information-import-to-careers && http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24915/associate-accounts-with-other-so-family-sites

Comment: yes (and blogger)

Answer (score 1):

My account is associated with SF and SU.

You can put a link to your public CV into your profile on each of the site, no problem.  Is that not enough?

Comment: I believe what he is saying, is that at the moment you can only associate your careers CV with your SO profile, not SF or SU

Comment: Sam_Cogan is correct