# Associate SE1.0 sites with current profile?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, association

Read: [Associate Accounts with other SO family sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24915/associate-accounts-with-other-so-family-sites)

Did not answer my question. Can SE1.0 sites be associated with our current profiles? Similar to gaming.SE or P.SE?

---

For clarification should this ever become a "feature-request" instead of a lost cause, all I want is to automatically have it fill in my details like it did when I joined gaming.SE or cooking.SE. I'm not looking for the point bonus. I just would like the auto association on the informational fields.

Comment: @JonSeigel ~ Thanks, wasn't sure how to tag it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SE 1.0 sites are completely independent of Stack Overflow, Super User, Server Fault and the new SE 2.0 sites.

Answer (score 1):

No, they cannot.